# Why does alcohol reduce shyness?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality

I find it very interesting that people who consume alcohol get less shy.

Therefore my question:

**Why does drinking alcohol reduce shyness?**

And are there any other (legal or illegal) substances who have such an effect on the human brain?

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the excitatory affect alcohol has on almost all neurotransmitters and their receptors, including serotonin, dopamine, and GABA.

Very, very broadly: 

Serotonin: Generally makes one seek a human connection.

Dopamine: Motivation to do things that are stimulating, like conversation.

Gaba: Surpresses anxiety.

GHB will do this even more - but it may do it to way too much of an extent.  (Mostly Gaba, but increases tyrosine hydroxylase as well which = more dopamine.)

MDMA obviously (it causes your serotonin receptors to instead of soaking up the neurotransmitter pump them out).

Amphetamines to an extent.  (Similar to the last two)